# Creating a composePipe function for Futures from Fluture

Tags: functional-programming, fluture

I wanted to make a compose function for piping and im stuck. I managed to make a pointfree pipe but cant figure out composing.

```
// pointfree
const pipe = fn => future => future.pipe(fn)


// compose pipes   // not working
const composePipe = (...fns) => (...args) => fns.reduceRight(  (future, fn) => future.pipe(fn), args)[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer your question eventually, but let's take a step back first.

An important thing to understand is that the pipe method *is just function application*. In other terms: `future.pipe (f) == f (future)`.

This means that your pipe function can be redefined as such:

```js
const pipe = fn => future => future.pipe(fn)
//to:
const pipe = fn => value => fn (value)
```

This new version of pipe works exactly the same way, except that it works on any values, not just Futures. But let's take a step back further even.

The signature of this function is as follows: `pipe :: (a -> b) -> a -> b`. It takes a function from A to B, and returns a function from A to B.

Wait a minute....

```js
const pipe = fn => value => fn (value)
//to:
const pipe = fn => fn
```

That new definition does the same thing. Except that it works on anything, not just Functions. Actually it's just the identity function. So a curried (you said point-free, but I think you meant curried) version of `future.pipe` is just the identity function.

So why is this? Because *all `.pipe` does is function application*. And you can apply your functions yourself.

---

Now to answer your next question about composing pipes. What you're actually looking for is something that takes a number of functions, and applies them in sequence.

If you're using Ramda, that's `pipe`. We can implement this ourselves though:

```js
const pipe = (...fns) => (...args) => fns.reduce ((args, f) => [f (...args)], args)[0]
```